# ∪n∈ℕ (ℝ\ [-n,n]) and ℝ\ ∩n∈ℕ (ℝ\ [-n,n])

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $[-n,n] = \{x ∈ \mathbb{R} : -n\leq x\leq n\}$, how can I write:

1) $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(\mathbb{R}\setminus[-n,n])$

2) $\mathbb{R}\setminus \left( \cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(\mathbb{R}\setminus [-n,n])\right)$

This is what I've got so far:

1) Using $n=0$, we have $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. Using $n=1$, we have $\mathbb{R}\setminus [-1,1]$. Using $n=2$, we have $\mathbb{R}\setminus [-2,2]$... Using $n=n$, we have $\mathbb{R}\setminus[-n,n]$. We see that if $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus [-n-1,n+1]$, then $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus[-n,n]$. Conclusion: $\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus[-n,n]\right)\subseteq \left(\mathbb{R}\setminus[-n-1,n+1]\right)$, so $\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus[-n,n] \right)=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

2) Using $n=0$, we have $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Using $n=1$, we have $\mathbb{R}\setminus[-1,1]$. Using $n=1$, we have $\mathbb{R}\setminus[-2,2]$ ... Using $n=n$, we have $\mathbb{R}\setminus[-n,n]$. However, if $x = n$, then $x \in \left(\mathbb{R}\setminus[-n+1,n-1]\right)$ and $x \notin \left(\mathbb{R}\setminus[-n,n]\right)$, so $\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus [-n+1,n-1] \right)\not\subset\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus[-n,n] \right)$. Thus, 
$$\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus [-n+1,n-1] \right)\cap \left(\mathbb{R}\setminus[-n,n] \right)=\emptyset$$ This means that $\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus[-n,n]\right)=\emptyset$. Therefore:

$$\mathbb{R}\setminus\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus[-n,n]\right)\right)=\mathbb{R} $$

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to check your textbook's/teacher's definitions to see whether $0\in\Bbb N$ in the first place.

Comment: For $(1)$ you have argued (or observed) that is if $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus[-n-1,n+1]$ then $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus [-n,n]$. This implies $\mathbb{R}\setminus[-n-1,n+1]\subset \mathbb{R}\setminus [-n,n]$, not the other way around. Also PLEASE try and write things down more clearly and use the basic latex needed to write the post- this was very hard to read and to edit. It does not take long to learn the basic syntax!

Comment: So I have ℝ∖[−n−1,n+1] ⊂ ℝ∖[−n,n].Taking a minimum n, n = 0, I have ℝ∖[−n,n] = ℝ∖[−0,0] = ℝ∖[0]. Now, if x ∈ (ℝ∖[0]), then x ∈  (ℝ∖[−n,n]).  Thus, (ℝ∖[−n,n])  ⊂  ℝ∖[0], so ∪n∈ℕ(ℝ∖[−n,n]) = ℝ∖[0].  Is this correct?

Comment: Do I have to prove by double inclusion?

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion is correct for 2, but the reasoning is bad; just because $A \nsubseteq B$ does not mean that $A\cap B=\varnothing$. (In fact, using the example of your actual proof, $(\Bbb R\setminus [-n+1,n-1]) \cap (\Bbb R\setminus [-n,n]) = \Bbb R\setminus [-n,n]$.)

You need to show that for all $x\in \Bbb R$, there exists some $n$ (which might depend on $x$) so that $x\notin \Bbb R\setminus [-n,n]$; then you know that this $x$ is not in the intersection of all the sets.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. Is my conclusion correct for 1?

Comment: @user125102  looks good.

Comment: This is my reasoning: if n = x, then ℝ∖[−n,n] = ℝ∖[−x,x] and x ∉ ℝ∖[−x,x]. Thus, x is not in the intersection of all the sets. Thus, for every x ∈ ℕ, x ∉ ℝ∖[−x,x] and the intersection of all the sets will be empty. Am I right?